# Is there an other meaning for 'Soap'?

Tags: word-usage

I was reading the newspaper today, there I found this: [image]

What is the use of the word 'soap' in this context? I am not a native speaker, and as far as I know, 'soap' only means the substance prepared from fat/oil that we use to wash our hands.

Comment: **Soap operas**.

Comment: ***Soap opera*** is recorded from 1939, as a disparaging reference to daytime radio dramas sponsored by soap manufacturers. (Etymonline)

Answer (score 2):

*Soap* here means *soap opera*.

**Soap opera:** a series of television or radio programmes about the lives and problems of a particular group of characters. The series continues over a long period and is broadcast (several times) every week. - [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soap-opera)

**Examples:**

1. It is her proud boast that she has never missed a single episode of the soap opera.
2. The new soap opera will be screened, wait for it, five times each day.